# OOP Java how to increase hit point and decrease mp?

Tags: java, oop, methods

How do I reference `hit_point` in the `useSkill` method? What I have now isn't increasing `hit_point` at all.

```
public int hit_point() {
    int total_power = this.power + this.weapon.getPower();
    return total_power;
}
//------------------------------------------------------why isn't this increasing the hit point at all?

public int useSkill() {
    this.mp=this.mp-1;
    this.skill--;
    return hit_point() +30;
}

public int getSkill() {
    return skill;
}
```

Comment: `hit_point()` isn't a value, it's a method name.  What are you expecting to be increased?

Comment: Ah okay. My instructions confused me. They say to increase hit_point if using skill. So I suppose I just need to increase power in order to do that, which I know how to do. Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

When returning values, a method isn't storing the return value unless you tell your program to store the value as so: `int totalHitPoint = useSkill()`. Then `useSkill()` would not only add to the total hit points already calculated, but it will be stored in a variable you can use on demand.